# Full URL for Task in a list via powershell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, task-list

I need to extract the full URL for a 'task' in a 'task list' via a PowerShell script.

My goal here is to extract this URL, report on it and the end user can click on the URL and it would take him directly to the Task in question.

Environment - SharePoint Enterpeise 2013

Thanks all

Comment: You want to generate a kind of Excel/csv file from PowerShell, and then distribute that file to end-users, correct?

Comment: What mode of the task you want your users to land at? DispForm (read) or EditForm (modify)?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the URL of an item in PowerShell is quite simple:

```
$web = get-SPWeb <SiteURL>
$list = $web.GetList("<AbsoluteURL_Of_The_List>") # or <Server-RelativeURL_Of_The_List>
$item = $list.GetItemById(<ItemId>)
$taskUrl = $item.URL
```

Comment: Thanks heapsI'll give it a go, pretty new to powershell so learning on the fly

Comment: @arax28 suggested an edit on this answer to change `<AbsoluteURL_Of_The_List>` to `<RelativeFromRoot_URL_Of_The_List>`. I rejected it since "RelativeFromRoot" is not clear enough to me: root of what? `GetList` needs a complete URL. I generally use the absolute URL (by combining the `SPWeb.Url` with the list site-relative URL) but it is true that you can use th _server-relative_ URL of the list instead (by combining `SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl` and the list site-relative URL). I could have _improved_ the suggestion made by @arax28, but actually I rejected it a bit too quickly, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in basic terms. you are not able to retrieve with the ID, so what I have done is to lock down the URL so that the users cannot change it with a bit of j-query (not with permissions). So now I can safely take the original title from sharepoint and use it to build the url, I can now get the URL.

Comment: Can you also post the way you are now getting the URLs, i.e. any script.